# Using Loop and If, ElseIf resulting in message: "Couldn't find "(what I am looking for)"

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Please not that this is one of the first VBA code I have written.
What I wrote was a mixture of a loop and If function. 
The code was supposed to go through column("AC"), if it finds an empty cell. 
It looks at the same row but in column D. Column D would have 350 possible values.
If the value of Column D is "one of 350 possible values" then give "EU" ElseIf... this continues for all 350

```
Dim i As Long
i = 1
Do While Cells(i, "AC").Value <> ""
    If Cells(i, "D").Value = "OPP-1305-9066" Then
        Cells(i, "AC").Value = EU
    ElseIf Cells(i, "D").Value = "OPP-1305-0773" Then
        Cells(i, "AC").Value = EU
    ElseIf Cells(i, "D").Value = "another one of 350" Then
        Cells(i, "AC").Value = EU
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: If those 350 values are fixed then store them in a sheet and read them into an array and then use that array to compare in a loop instead of writing 350 `IF` lines

Comment: If `Cells(i, "AC").Value` is going to be set to `EU` (or should that be `"EU"`?) regardless of what the value is, why even have *one* conditional? Consider using a *data validation list* in column D, to restrict the values to legal ones (which you store in a separate table with 350 rows, then define a named range to enclose the column that contains the 350 values, and use that named range as your "list" for data validation. Bam, a thousand lines of code gone.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your questions is, but unless EU is a variable, you are missing brackets. Also you only loop while column AC is not empty, so if AC2 is empty but there's more data after cell AC4 you're not checking it.

And most importantly, 350 elseif statements, wow! :) You will benefit from learning about arrays/collections.